# Beginner Arithmetic Math Operations (Java)

Tags: java, operator-precedence, arithmetic-expressions

The question says 5 / 3 * 2.0 / (4 % 3) + 5 = 7.0

For some reason I don't understand why this makes sense at all. I start with dividing 5/6.0 = .83, then divide it by (4%3 which is 1) and add 5 but I'm not getting that answer. Can you explain it in detail.

Thank you.

Comment: this is much more like math problem instead of coding problem

Answer (score 5):

The rule of [BODMAS/VBODMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is what you've to remember here. Let's split it up and see how it goes.

Expression: `5 / 3 * 2.0 / (4 % 3) + 5`

```
Step 1: 5 /3 gives 1 - Integer division
Step 2: 1 * 2.0 gives 2.0 - Multiplication
Step 3: 4 % 3 gives 1 - Modulus
Step 4: 2.0 / 1 gives 2.0 - Division
Step 5: 2.0 + 5 gives 7.0 - Addition
```